# Recording Yamaha P115 with Focusrite Scarlet 8i6

Tags: ableton-live

I apologize for the insane noob questions.

I'm entirely new to recording. I've recorded some MIDI in the past, but not much.
I recently purchased a Focusrite Scarlet 8i6 to record my Yamaha P115 with. 
I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly how to initiate the recording process with it. 
I have two 1/4 inch TRS cables running from the P115 into the Audio interface in input ports 3 and 4, with a single pair of AKG K240's connected to the front right headphone port. The Audio interface is functional, I do have the correct drivers installed and Ableton 10 Live is recognizing it. 
Am I supposed to be able to hear the audio while connected to the audio interface? How do I know if it's even recording? I'm having a pretty hard time finding the correct resources, All I can really find is user documentation on the 8i6 but that hasn't been helping much.[image]

Comment: Do you want to record MIDI or audio from P115?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you are trying to record audio or MIDI from your P115. The difference being audio will be the actual sound made by your piano and MIDI will be the data for pressing a key on the piano (velocity, note pressed, length, etc.). If you are trying to record the audio, I will say that the Focusrites do not monitor very loud so I would recommend turning on input monitoring in Ableton. If you are trying to record MIDI then you will not hear anything unless you have a MIDI plugin/instrument selected on your track.